# Why does "\n" create a new line even when told not to?

Tags: javascript, newline

I am having a problem with "\n" creating a line even when it is told not to when copying. The fix is probably something simple that I am just not seeing for some reason. I would appreciate any input or coaching on this problem.

(Please only give me Javascript answers as I am not interested in jquery or other methods)

```
       <script type="text/javascript">

        if (pullDownResponseE == "")
        {
        }
        else {
        var pullDownValuesE = document.getElementById("taskOne");
        var pullDownResponseE = pullDownValuesE.options[pullDownValuesE.selectedIndex].value;
        stuffToCopy = stuffToCopy + "\n" + pullDownResponseE;
        }


        if (pullDownResponseF == "")
        {
        }
        else{
        var pullDownValuesF = document.getElementById("taskTwo");
        var pullDownResponseF = pullDownValuesF.options[pullDownValuesF.selectedIndex].value;
        stuffToCopy = stuffToCopy + "\n" + pullDownResponseF;
        }

        </script>
```

As you can see, pullDownResponseF and pullDownReponseE should do nothing if my dropdown value equals "" and  this portion works for the most part, it doesn't execute any of the else code EXCEPT for the new line "\n" part.

Can anyone explain what is going wrong here?

EDIT: Having more code might help here. I'll only include the essential portions since it is so long.

```
        <script type="text/javascript">

        function copyNotesTemplate()
        { 

        var stuffToCopy = document.getElementById('myForm').value;
        if(stuffToCopy.length > 1)
        {
        var stuffToCopy = "PT meets criteria" + "\n" + document.getElementById('myForm').value;
        }
        if(document.getElementById('noPtCriteria').checked)
        {
        var stuffToCopy = document.getElementById('noPtCriteria').value;
        }


        if (pullDownResponsee == "")
        {
        }
        else {
        var pullDownValuese = document.getElementById("taskOne");
        var pullDownResponsee = pullDownValuese.options[pullDownValuese.selectedIndex].value;
        stuffToCopy = stuffToCopy + "\n" + pullDownResponsee;
        }


        if (pullDownResponsef == "")
        {
        }
        else{
        var pullDownValuesf = document.getElementById("taskTwo");
        var pullDownResponsef = pullDownValuesf.options[pullDownValuesf.selectedIndex].value;
        stuffToCopy = stuffToCopy + "\n" + pullDownResponsef;
        }

        if (pullDownResponseg == "")
        {
        }
        else{
        var pullDownValuesg = document.getElementById("taskThree");
        var pullDownResponseg = pullDownValuesg.options[pullDownValuesg.selectedIndex].value;
        stuffToCopy = stuffToCopy + "\n" + pullDownResponseg;
        }

        var tempValues = document.getElementById('whatUpdate').value
        if(tempValues.length > 1) 
        {
        var stuffToCopy = stuffToCopy + "Updated" + " " + document.getElementById('whatUpdate').value + " ";
        }
        else{
        }

        var tempValuess = document.getElementById('whatInfo').value
        if(tempValuess.length > 1) 
        {
        var stuffToCopy = stuffToCopy + "per" + " " + document.getElementById('whatInfo').value + "\n";
        }
        else{
        }

        var tempValue = document.getElementById('whatDSCRP').value
        if(tempValue.length > 1) 
        {
        var stuffToCopy = stuffToCopy + document.getElementById('whatDSCRP').value + " " + "dscrp on Collection tube and trf was resolved using" + " ";
        }
        else{
        }


        var tempValue = document.getElementById('resolveIT').value
        if(tempValue.length > 1) 
        {
        var stuffToCopy = stuffToCopy + document.getElementById('resolveIT').value + " ";
        }
        else{
        }

        var tempValue = document.getElementById('tubeCorrect').value
        if(tempValue.length > 1) 
        {
        var stuffToCopy = stuffToCopy + "trf was" + " " + document.getElementById('tubeCorrect').value;
        }
        else{
        }


        if(stuffToCopy.length > 1)
        {
        var stuffToCopy = stuffToCopy + "\n" + document.getElementById('moreNotes').value;
        }
        else{
        }

        if (pullDownResponsesu == "")
        {
        }
        else{
        var pullDownValuesu = document.getElementById("mod33Apply");
        var pullDownResponsesu = pullDownValuesu.options[pullDownValuesu.selectedIndex].value;
        stuffToCopy = stuffToCopy + "\n" + pullDownResponsesu;
        }

        if (pullDownResponsesb == "")
        {
        }
        else{
        var pullDownValuesb = document.getElementById("resultICR");
        var pullDownResponsesb = pullDownValuesb.options[pullDownValuesb.selectedIndex].value;
        stuffToCopy = stuffToCopy + "\n" + pullDownResponsesb + "," + " ";
        }

        if (pullDownResponsesc == "")
        {
        }
        else{
        var pullDownValuesc = document.getElementById("moneyNCIS");
        var pullDownResponsesc = pullDownValuesc.options[pullDownValuesc.selectedIndex].value;
        stuffToCopy = stuffToCopy + pullDownResponsesc + " ";
        }

        if (pullDownResponsesd == "")
        {
        }
        else{
        var pullDownValuesd = document.getElementById("resultMMT");
        var pullDownResponsesd = pullDownValuesd.options[pullDownValuesd.selectedIndex].value;
        stuffToCopy = stuffToCopy + pullDownResponsesd;
        }


        if(stuffToCopy.length > 1)
        {
        var stuffToCopy = stuffToCopy + " " + "Reason:" + " " + document.getElementById('whyNotEligible').value;
        }
        else{
        }

        if (pullDownResponsesa == "")
        {
        }
        else{
        var pullDownValuesa = document.getElementById("testReleased");
        var pullDownResponsesa = pullDownValuesa.options[pullDownValuesa.selectedIndex].value;
        stuffToCopy = stuffToCopy + "\n" + pullDownResponsesa;
        }
        window.clipboardData.setData('text', stuffToCopy);
        }
        </script>
```

If somebody skips filling out a note field or skips a dropdown in this example then it will not execute the code like I intended but it does create a new line when copied like this:

taskOne selected

(extra line here since task two wasn't selected)

taskThree selected

I would like there not to be an extra line between Task one and three if task two is skipped. Like this:

taskOne selected

taskThree selected

Note: I know that having else {} is pointless but it helps me visually.

I created snips of exactly what it looks like when copy/pasted from my tool that you can view here if you would like:

Example 1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMI4z.jpg

Example 2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykAKb.jpg

Here is an example of my html as well:

```
<html lang="en">
  What tasks are needed for the case?
  <br />
  <select class="style3" id="taskOne">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="ABN needed">ABN needed</option>
  <option value="Auth needed">Auth needed</option>
  </select>
  </html>
```

Comment: try adding alert(variable) after setting variables...it'll tell you what they are.  your code does not make too much sense as it is...it is very difficult for us to figure out what you're trying to do.(that is likely why somebody downvoted it...try putting working code in and you'll get more responses). welcome to SO!

Comment: I simply want to know if there is a reason "\n" creates a new line when it isn't supposed to. I can edit my post to include the entire function but it is extremely long and figured it would frustrate people more than it would help. I have tried alerts but it doesn't answer my question unfortunately.

Comment: *"it doesn't execute any of the else code EXCEPT for the new line "\n" part"* - there's no way it would execute just the last part of the else block. There must be something else going on in the code not shown. By the way, why do you have empty if blocks? Why not use != in your if conditions?

Comment: Where is this newline "created" exactly? if stufftocopy is empty to begin with, and one of those pulldownresponse is not blank, you will end up with a leading "\n" in stufftocopy

Comment: This code it a portion of a note formatting HTA tool I created for a friend's work. Having it empty doesn't make sense in most situations but it is a special circumstance. And as far as the != part goes, I don't know what that is. I am still fairly new to this.

Comment: `!=` is the [not equal operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Inequality_(!)) (AKA the inequality operator).

Comment: @user1269942 please don't ever motivate someone to use `alert()` for debugging! There are browser consoles and standard js logging for this purpose.

Comment: The browsers need to deprecate alert asap.  Ewww.

Comment: "\n" always creates a new line. You can't "tell it not to".

Comment: It's not meant to be in a browser Rooster. Like I said before it is an HTA:APPLICATION. Just a note formatting tool.

Comment: I don't think you read anything other than the title PreferenceBean. If you would take a look at the code I am asking why it is creating an extra line even when it doesn't meet requirements in my if/else statements.

Comment: @AnakinDawson, but every time you're in the else you add a "\n"

Comment: @AnakinDawson, can you make a minimal! snippet of your problem? I suppose we don't need those 20 cases, 2 should be enough.

Comment: @Gavriel Yes, if it meets the else requirements then I want the line but if the value equals "" or basically nothing then I don't want it to. if{} should do nothing (intended) but it still creates the new line for some reason and the only thing I can think of that is causing that is the "n\" part in the else statements.

Comment: Some things that don't make sense to me: I've never seen the use of a form property named value `.getElementById('myForm').value`. Are you sure you want to do that to begin your function? Also, you are throwing away the value of the variable `stuffToCopy` by using `=` with every `if{}` statement. Are you sure you couldn't use `+=` to append further values like `stuffToCopy+= 'strings'`. Lastly, you don't have the ability(reputation) to chat so helping you further with boundless questions about your code logic is not feasible.

Comment: @FactoryAidan The myForm value is just the id of a textbox, this is a rough draft and I haven't got creative with the names yet. My coding knowledge is fairly limited so I have just relied on what I learned from a mentor many years ago. I have never used += before so I just stuck with what I am familiar with. I'm not sure if SO allows links but I will attempt to link pictures of my tool so that you guys can see what it is doing exactly. I think that would be most beneficial in this situation.

Answer (score 3):

No, it doesn't add a new line, see:

```js
stuffToCopy = "";
controlGroup = "a\nb";
pullDownResponseE = "";

if (pullDownResponseE == "")
{
}
else {
    var pullDownValuesE = "taskOne";
    var pullDownResponseE = "value";
    stuffToCopy = stuffToCopy + "\n" + pullDownResponseE;
}
alert("stuffToCopy:"+stuffToCopy+";(no new-line here)\ncontrolGroup:"+controlGroup);
```

My guess is that your html is printed in such away that the values you get from the inputs contain an extra new-line at the end. Try changing your html to be 1 line, without new-lines, and test again.

Instead of:

```
<option value="a
">b
</option>
```

try:

```
<option value="a">b</option>
```

Comment: That's definitely a good guess but I can assure you the html is fine, it is all done properly with the dropdowns exactly like your example there. I'll add an example of the html in my original post in a minute or two.

Comment: Was working on that, I just uploaded 2 examples to imgur and put them in the original post. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Alright so I fixed it, should have used the almighty document.getElementById instead of attempting to use pullDownReponse for my if statements..

I simply changed the if statements like this:

```
 if (pullDownResponseg == "")
 {
 }
```

To this:

```
if (document.getElementById("taskThree").value == "")
 {
 }
```

Thanks for the help from the sincere. (and ridiculous non-answers from the others)